# Html.DropdownListFor not submitting selected item in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I am using Html.DropDownListFor to sort search results. In Chrome/Firefox/Edge when an item is selected, the form posts correctly with the parameter containing the ascending or descending value to sort the results, however in IE11, the form resubmits but the value in the model for the sort identifier is null.

This is the form

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, PageEditing.PageIsInEditMode ? FormMethod.Post : FormMethod.Get,
    new { action = Model.Layout.SearchActionUrl, @class = "rr-search-form", id = "rr-search", name = "SearchForm" }))
    {
        <input type="text" id="rrSearchInput" class="rr-input rr-input--search" name="q" aria-label="søk" value="@Model.SearchedQuery.Cleaner(200)" />
        <button type="submit" title="Søk etter rapporter og innhold">
        </button>
    }
```

And this is the sort dropdown:

```
@{
    Model.SelectItems = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text=Html.Translate("/searchpagetemplate/sortascending"), Value="ascending"},
        new SelectListItem {Text=Html.Translate("/searchpagetemplate/sortdescending"), Value="descending"}
    };
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectSortIdentifier, Model.SelectItems, Html.Translate("/searchpagetemplate/sorttype"),
    new { @class = "rr-search-sorting__select rr-font--meta",
        form = "rr-search",
        aria_label = "Sorter søkeresultater",
        onchange = "SearchForm.submit()", id = "rr-search-sort" })
```

When an option is selected in the dropdown, the form submits with the SelectSortIdentifier parameter included in modern browsers but not IE

Comment: Can you please check if it shows any error or warning message in the console? If it shows you any error than try to inform us about that may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: No, there are no errors - the form is submitted as it should be, and I can step through the code and see that the sort parameter is null